# Java Spring Application - Integration with Azure AD for SSO

Tags: spring-security, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml, spring-saml

I have a Java Spring MVC application (**note that its not spring boot**).

We have a requirement to implement SSO for the users of our application. I did some research, the identity provider (IDP) in our case is Azure AD. The service provider would be my application in this case. I am thinking of using SAML protocol for SSO.
Also note - The application is http based (not HTTPS)

**What I've done so far -**

I've created an Enterprise Application on Azure and configured entityId and replyURL. I also added a user for this application.

**Where I'm stuck** -
Although I did read the related Spring documentation to achieve this, since I'm a newbie here, I still don't have a clear path as to how can I take this forward in my application. I found some solutions, they seem to be examples for spring boot. Can someone please help me with guides as to how this can be done in Java Spring? Which maven dependency I could use and any sample example to start working with SAML? A step by step explanation would be highly appreciated, thankyou.

Also, any other options than SAML would also be fine.

Comment: you could try the Graph API and OAuth to Azure but AFAIK Azure will not respond to non-https endpoints. Any endpoint that consumes personal information must use https https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Security SAML extension (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/index.html) had an example web app. You may read the referenced doc and apply it to Spring Security SAML. It should not be too much difference.

Answer (score 0):

I’m very glad to register the flow in the event of implementing Azure AD B2C **OIDC/OAuth** protocol with existing Spring MVC architecture.
Below Spring docs reveal that how was our existing project's spring-security layer being served in the context of filter-chain.

> *Pre-requisites*
>
> - [Authentication Filter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html#servlet-authentication-usernamepasswordauthenticationfilter) - Form Based Login with Legacy IDP
> - [Authentication Manager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-requests.html) – Providing the user details authorities along with http session object

For accomplishing this *Azure B2C Integration*, we've gone thro' lot of repos but most of them are relying with Java config based but we were interested on ***Spring namespace with limited code/architectural change***.
Then finally we came to the conclusion that how to extend the spring default auth-filter/manager for getting valid session object from security context based on the Azure provided (id/access) token after the successful user authentication.

> *Customizing Spring-Security*
>
> The detailed documentation on how to *extend auth-filter/manager* is available [here](http://terasolunaorg.github.io/guideline/5.2.1.RELEASE/en/Security/Authentication.html#how-to-extend) with © reserved by [terasoluna.org](https://terasolunaorg.github.io)

We customized the spring security in such a manner that auth-filter will carry the token_validation against the given token from Azure and authentication manager will extract user details such as roles/privileges w.r.t to the object-id mapped in our DB's user entity.
Once the Spring security customization is done then we can able to integrate the Authorization-server [Azure in our case] and Resource-server [Existing Spring Application] by following the [conventional methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-sign-in-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow).